# JavaScript issue passing value across pages

Tags: javascript

I have this JavaScript code that processes and displays the value onto the same page; the value is entered using a textbox. I want to pass this value onto another page. this my code:

**index.html**:

```
 <form action="display.html" method="post" id="name-form">
        <p>
            <label>Your full Name</label>:<br />
            <input type="text" name="fullName">
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </p>
    </form>
    <!-- <p id="result"></p>-->
    <script>
        var form = document.getElementById('name-form');
        form.onsubmit = function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var result = document.getElementById('result');
            result.innerHTML = 'Hi ' + form.fullName.value;
            console.log(form.fullName.value);
            this.reset();
        };
    </script>
```

**display.html**

```
 <p id="result"></p>
  <script>
        var form = document.getElementById('name-form');
        form.onsubmit = function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var result = document.getElementById('result');
            result.innerHTML = 'Hi ' + form.fullName.value;
            console.log(form.fullName.value);
            this.reset();
        };
    </script>
```

my question is how do I get the value that is entered into the textbox to display onto another page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a static website, you should consider storing that value in `localStorage`. So that value will be available all across your web pages.

And if you have a dynamic website you can store that value in `db` and then request `db` for that value when you're on some other page.

Choose anyone of the approaches that fits in your case and application.

Read here about [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Answer (score 0):

Use [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie).

Save the name: `document.cookie = "name=" + name`

Load the name: `name = document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)name\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1");`

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie/Simple_document.cookie_framework) for a simpler way to load cookies